# Hide paginator in jqgrid when there is only one page of

Tags: jqgrid, pagination

How can I hide the pagination in jqgrid footer when all of the results fit on one page?

I think this should be the default behaviour, am I right?

Answer (score 3):

If you use server data source, you would need loadComplete event

```
loadComplete: function(data) {
    if (data.total <= 1) {
        $("#pager").hide();
    } else {
        $("#pager").show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not the default behavior of jqgrid. You have to use a condition to hide the same. You can do the same in `gridComplete()` function. You can either hide the pager or empty it as shown below

```
gridComplete: function(){
  if(condition)          
   $( '#' + gridId + 'pager_center' ).hide();
  // or you can also use
   $('#pager_center').empty();
},
```